# How to adjust equation size to linewidth and keep line spacing

Tags: beamer, fontsize

I'm preparing a beamer presentation. Compilation is done using pdflatex.
One of the frames includes several equations and one of the equations is too long to fit into the page width.
I wish to adjust the entire frame font size automatically to fit into the page while preserving the original line spacing.
Please note that I do not want to change the font size in other frames.

Edit:
Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43]{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\mode<presentation>
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamerfont{title in sidebar}{size=\fontsize{5.5pt}{6pt}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{author in sidebar}{size=\fontsize{5.5pt}{6pt}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{normal}{size=\fontsize{5pt}\selectfont}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\parbox[c][][c]{\linewidth}{\centering\small~\vspace{1.0em}\\%
                                               ~{\smash{\textbf{\Large\insertframetitle}}}~\\%
                                               ~{\smash{\rm\insertframesubtitle}}~}}
%
\makeatletter
\def\section@yeshadestyle{}%
\def\section@noshadestyle{\color{section in sidebar.fg}}%
\def\subsection@yeshadestyle{}%
\def\subsection@noshadestyle{}%\color{subsection in sidebar.fg}}%
\def\scondfont{\protect\@scondfont[\thesection]}
\def\@scondfont [#1]{\ifnum#1=\c@section%
                     \section@noshadestyle\else%            yes section
                     \section@yeshadestyle\fi}%             no  section
\def\sscondfont{\protect\@sscondfont[\thesection.\thesubsection]}
\def\@sscondfont [#1.#2]{\ifnum#1=\c@section\ifnum#2=\c@subsection%
                         \subsection@noshadestyle\else%     yes section & yes subsection
                         \subsection@yeshadestyle\fi\else%  yes section & no  subsection
                         \subsection@yeshadestyle\fi}%      no  section & no  subsection
\makeatother

\def\safe\\{\texorpdfstring{\\}{,~}}%
\title[High-Order Embedded Finite Difference Schemes for Initial Boundary Value Problems]
      {High-Order Embedded Finite Difference\safe\\Schemes for Initial Boundary Value Problems\safe\\Involving Mixed Derivative Terms in Complex Domains}
\def\SupervisorsGAP{\texorpdfstring{\scriptsize\vspace{1em}\\Supervised~by:~}{,~}}
\author[Mr. Tomer Livneh]
       {Mr. Tomer Livneh\SupervisorsGAP%
        Dr. Adi Ditkowski}
\date{September, 2015}

\gdef\ttx#1{\text{\tiny{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{The two-dimensional case}{The scheme}%
    \onslide<1->
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            $\frac{d{\bf V}}{dt} = ({\cal M}^{(x)} + P^T {\cal M}^{(y)}P){\bf V} + {\bf G}^{(x)} + P^T{\bf G}^{(y)} + {\bf F} \;\; \nonumber$
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \onslide<2->
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\parbox{\linewidth}{%
            \begin{equation}
                    {\cal M}^{(x)} = \left [ \begin{array}{llll}
                                                M^{(x)}_1\\
                                                & M^{(x)}_2\\
                                                & & \ddots\\
                                                & & & M^{(x)}_{M_{R}}
                                                \end{array}\right ]; {\cal M}^{(y)} = \left [ \begin{array}{llll}                                                                                                M^{(y)}_1 \\                                                                                                     & M^{(y)}_2\\                                                                                                    & & \ddots\\                                                                                                     & & & M^{(y)}_{M_{C}}                                                                                          \end{array}\right ] ; \nonumber
            \end{equation}
            \begin{flalign}
                    M^{(x)}_k &= D^{(x)}_k -\tau_{L_{k}}A_{L_{k}}-\tau_{R_{k}}A_{R_{k}} &\nonumber \\
                    M^{(y)}_{j} &= D^{(y)}_j - \tau_{B_{j}}A_{B_{j}}-\tau_{T_{j}}A_{T_{j}} &\nonumber \\
                {\bf G}^{(x)} & = \left[ (\tau_{L_{1}}{\bf g}_{L_{1}}+\tau_{R_{1}}{\bf g}_{R_{1}}), \ldots , (\tau_{L_{k}}{\bf g}_{L_{k}}+\tau_{R_{k}}{\bf g}_{R_{k}}), \ldots ,(\tau_{L_{M_{R}}}{\bf g}_{L_{M_{R}}}+\tau_{R_{M_{R}}}{\bf g}_{R_{M_{R}}}) \right] &\nonumber\\
                {\bf G}^{(y)}& = \left[ (\tau_{B_{1}}{\bf g}_{B_{1}}+\tau_{T_{1}}{\bf g}_{T_{1}}), \ldots ,(\tau_{B_{j}}{\bf g}_{B_{j}} +\tau_{T_{j}} {\bf g}_{T_{j}}),\ldots ,(\tau_{B_{M_{C}}}{\bf g}_{B_{M_{C}}}+\tau_{T_{M_{C}}}{\bf g}_{T_{M_{C}}}) \right] &\nonumber
            \end{flalign}
        }}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Would you mind posting your document's preamble as well as the frame that contains the equations of interest? Which TeX format -- pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, or something else? -- do you employ? How the squeezing/font size adjustment should be performed may depend on the answers to these questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that preserving the line spacing is the right thing to do.

With

```
\begin{frame}
\expandafter\small\expandafter\baselineskip\the\baselineskip
...
\end{frame}
```

you should get what you want. Instead of `\small` you can try `\footnotesize`

Comment: The suggestion works, but even using `\tiny` there's still an overfull by 40pt.  Abbreviating the formulas seems the only reasonable solution.